# Code Composer Studio: unresolved symbols remain

Tags: c, msp430, code-composer, msp432

You may encounter a build error: 'unresolved symbols remain'. This may be because you have not installed CCS along with SimpleLink SDK properly for the MSP432. To fix this, here a solution that you can try, courtesy of my Professors:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits: Prof Ian Vince McLoughlin, Prof Muhamed Fauzi bin Abbas

Install CCS (I used the latest, CCS10.4.0.00006_win64.zip [1.15Gbytes]).

Unzip, then do a custom install, and select the MSP432 tools. Default location. You can get it from: https://www.ti.com/tool/CCSTUDIO

Meanwhile, download the installer named; simplelink_msp432p4_sdk_3_40_01_02.exe [232 MBytes] from: https://www.ti.com/tool/download/SIMPLELINK-MSP432-SDK

Once CCS has been installed, launch it and make sure it is running fine. You might need to reboot your computer.  Once this works OK, continue.

Now tun the simplelink installer .exe from step 2. Just accept all of the default options.

Once it has finished, run CCS (or restart CCS if it is already running using File -> Restart).

Once CCS is running, after some time, it will pop up a window near the bottom of the screen saying "Updates Available". Click on that window and allow it to do the default updates (this will auto-update three components).

Wait for that to complete.

In CCS, launch  View -> Resource Explorer Offline.

Click the red crossed-out CLOUD icon (there are 3 icons, the cloud, a home icon and an eye icon). Wait for it to sync to the cloud. It can be slow.

Once the page reloads, scroll down and install the offline package (in one of the rectangular boxes) called Arm code generation tools - compiler. Use the pull-down option to choose version 20.2.4 and click the install icon next to that box.

Wait for this to install. It shouldn't take long.

Once that has been installed, restart CCS.

Now go to View -> Getting started. Click on "Import Project" and Browse the search-directory until you get to; C:/ti/simplelink_msp432p4_sdk_3_40_01_02/examples/nortos/MSP_EXP432P401R/driverlib/empty

Click "Select Folder"

It will show you a Discovered Project. Tick the box next to that to select that project and then press "Finish". This will import an empty DriverLib project into your workspace. You may rename this project and this becomes your own project.

If there is any problem at this stage, restart CCS and go back to clicking on the red crossed-out cloud (one time it failed for me and I needed to repeat that step).

Go to View -> Project Explorer and you should see it there. You can click on main.c and then try to compile it (the hammer icon in the toolbar) and debug it (the bug icon in the toolbar). If your MSP432 is connected to your computer it will download and execute.